# Redirecionar Página ip interno/externo

Tags: windows, iis

Tenho uma página em HTML e já a consigo visualizar internamente e externamente através do iis do windows server 2003.

Estou dentro de uma rede onde está ligado o Windows server2003 e quero aceder ao IP externo dentro dessa mesma rede e não consigo. 
Mas se for pelo IP interno funciona.

Quero saber se existe forma de redireccionar os IP. Sabendo se estou internamente ou externamente a rede.

Obrigado

Comment: Não consegui entender sua pergunta. Consegue melhorar a explicação dela, com um exemplo do problema?

Comment: Tentei explicar melhor a minha situação

Comment: Qual o problema? É porque os usuários tem que saber os 2 ips pra acessar e vc quer acabar com isso?

Comment: Exactamente. isso @Intruso

Comment: @ChrisAdler tu vais ter que criar regras de `loopback` no teu `Firewall` http://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat tenta ver se esse link não te ajuda.

Comment: Você tem IP fixo, confere? Você tem um serviço de DNS externo? (com algum dominio .com.br da vida) e um servidor de DNS interno?

Comment: tenho um dominio que é gerida pela operadora. DNS interno sim tenho. E claro IP fixo :)

Comment: Então qual o problema com minha resposta? :) Veja o que falta, assim posso melhorar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use o DNS para resolver o problema**. O serviço de resolução de nomes, além de fornecer um nome amigável para o aplicativo (Ex.: http://meuapp.empresa.com.br) vai resolver o problema de roteamento fornecendo aos clientes o IP adequado de acordo com a rede que a máquina estiver.

Um cenário comum atualmente, é o caso onde você tem um servidor de DNS externo para o seu dominio publico e um interno para a rede corporativa (as vezes, é o mesmo servidor de dominio - AD).

Então, basta você adicionar uma entrada no servidor externo com o endereço para a aplicação (Ex.: http://meuapp.empresa.com.br) apontando para o IP externo.

Com isso, todas as maquinas externas a sua rede já podem acessar a aplicação pelo novo endereço, supondo que seu site está publicado na porta 80.

E depois, você vai precisar realizar uma transferência de Zona do DNS externo com seu dominio para o Interno, so que no seu servidor interno,a entrada de DNS deve retornar o IP da rede interna para o aplicativo em questão.

Isso fara com que para aquela zona em particular, quando a máquina estiver na rede interna, a prioridade sobre o endereço de DNS seja do servidor interno, entao o endereço retornado pelo DNS será o endereço interno do servidor.

Quando o computador estiver na rede externa, o DNS prioritário será o da WEB retornando o endereço externo.

Com isso, as maquinas passam a acessar o aplicativo pelo nome amigável e o DNS se encarrega de fornecer o IP adequado através da prioridade na Zona do DNS de acordo com a rede em que a máquina estiver.

Atenção:

- Você deve verificar se seu fornecedor para o Domínio permite
  transferências de Zona.
- Se você usar neste dominio outras aplicações com endereços externos, tenha certeza de serviços de redundância não fornecem IPs diferentes para o site, pois o seu DNS interno vai assumir a zona e fornecer o IP errado.
- Um Load balancer as vezes faz distribuição de carga com base em várias instâncias de aplicações com ips diferentes, verifique adequadamente.

Se puder, teste as transferências de zona em horários não comerciais e verifique todos os domínios e subdominios pertinentes.

Transferência de Zona:
https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/cc781340(v=ws.10).aspx

**Outra alternativa é verificar suas configurações em relação ao Loopback** (veja: http://help.screenconnect.com/Cannot_access_external_IP_address_from_LAN). Mas, existem outras implicações, como modificar as suas configurações de firewall e as vezes, por segurança, essas configurações estão desabilitadas. Isso também pode exigir configurações em locais distintos (vários firewalls) e com o aumento das aplicações, usar um nome amigável é melhor em termos de manutenção e controle das regras.

Os usuarios geralmente também ficam mais felizes.

Answer (score 0):

Confirme se estou correto, basicamente você disponibilizou uma página HTML no IIS e somente consegue acessar a respectiva pelo IP interno correto?

Se sim tente verificar estas prováveis causas:

- Verifique se sua porta 80 está aberta no firewall.
- Verifique se os bindings do seu IIS permitem atender requisições através do ip externo.
- Verifique se o roteador(caso esteja ao seu alcance e a infraestrutura esteja sobre seus cuidados) está permitindo acessos a porta 80.
- Se estiver rodando essa aplicação em casa você precisa lembrar que seu IP publico não aponta diretamente para o seu computador portanto você deve criar uma configuração NAT para redirecionar as requisições da porta 80 para o seu ip interno.

Comment: Consigo aceder internamente com ip interno e externamente com ip externo. Mas se for ao contrario já não funciona, ou seja, com ip externo dentro da rede.

Comment: De uma olhada nestas opções: http://help.screenconnect.com/Cannot_access_external_IP_address_from_LAN